# Determine the origin of a WM_CLOSE message

Tags: windows, sendmessage

I have an app that prompts the user for confirmation on exit, which is (indirectly) done by opening a confirmation dialog when the `WM_CLOSE` message is received. However the message is also sent by the task manager when the user uses end task on the process.

Because I prevent the window from closing with the confirmation dialog, task manager sees it as the process hanging and forcefully terminates it preventing the app from doing a graceful exit when it's possible.

Is there any way to determine if it's the user closing the window from the message (e.g. clicking the close button, or Alt+F4), and not the task manager? As the message's parameters are unused the only way I could think of is checking for mouse events or `WM_SYSCOMMAND` that were received some time before the `WM_CLOSE` is received, but I'm unsure if this would handle all cases.

Comment: From what I've tried on Windows 10, it does ask nicely with the close event at first if it has a window and is not a background process in the task manager, but if that doesn't go through the terminate follows soon after.
Though I'm a bit confused by WM_SYSCOMMAND as I don't receive it when clicking the X button, only with Alt+F4 and the window context menu

Answer (score 0):

I assume the task manager calls `EndTask`. Perhaps in the old days it only sent `WM_CLOSE` but it seems to send `WM_SYSCOMMAND` when I tested now so there are no clues in the messages you can use, it just looks like a normal Alt+F4.

If your app is asking about unsaved changes in a document, I would say, put up the dialog regardless and just accept the hard termination if that is what the user wants.

If you are just trying to prevent an accidental close, call `GetForegroundWindow` in `WM_CLOSE`. If you are not foreground, it was not an accidental close.